# steps to build a NHibernate data layer

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate

What are the proper steps to design and implmement a NHibernate data layer ?
Should I include a step to let NHibernate to generate the schema defintion rather than coding the schema by myself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends whether you are starting from scratch or not.  For new projects I use NHibernate to create the schema for me.  For existing projects that I want to switch to NH I usually do the db changes manually.  You need to be a little careful though in regards to your mapping and the db you are using.  If you do not use the correct mapping with the correct db mapping you might have performance issues, as well as objects might update themselves without you knowing and when you flush the session your db will be updated.

In regards to using an actual data layer I usually use the [Automatic Transaction Management](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.ATM-Facility.ashx)  & the [NHibernate Facility](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.NHibernate-Facility.ashx) from the Castle project.  You can also make your own configuration builder for the NHibernate Facility so that it works with Fluent NHibernate as well.

Comment: Thanks Evangelos . I am using an existing db ( but I can discard it if NH does a better job in generating db) and am looking for info  about switching to NH. What is this problem about object updating themselves ?  and what are the performance issues ?  Is fluent NH a preferred approach over doing manual XML mapping ?

Comment: For example if in your db you have a number field as null and if in your nh mapping you have it as not null, when NH retrieves the object the field will be set to 0.  NH will think the value has changed and when you flush the session it will actually update the db is your FlushMode is Auto.

Comment: In regards to Fluent NH, its my preference due to the fact it allows me to do mappings quicker than NH.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very open question.

Regarding the schema generation, yes, it's usually better to let NHibernate generate it.

For architectures based on NHibernate, you can check [Sharp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/), [Effectus](https://github.com/ayende/Effectus) and [uNhAddIns](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/)